# Flink Table API join tables in a streaming mode

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have registered two jdbc tables in a my flink application, and want to join them and convert result into regular datastream.
But when I join the tables getting error

`Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Table sink 'default_catalog.default_database.Unregistered_DataStream_Sink_1' doesn't support consuming update and delete changes which is produced by node Join(joinType=[LeftOuterJoin], where=[((id = asset_id) AND (owner_id = owner_id0))], select=[owner_id, id, poi_id, gateway_id, owner_id0, asset_id, tag_id, role], leftInputSpec=[NoUniqueKey], rightInputSpec=[NoUniqueKey])`

Code

```scala
    val assetTableDescriptor = TableDescriptor.forConnector("jdbc")
      .option(JdbcConnectorOptions.URL, s"jdbc:mysql://${memsqlConfig("host")}:${memsqlConfig("port")}/${memsqlConfig("dbname")}")
      .option(JdbcConnectorOptions.USERNAME, memsqlConfig("user"))
      .option(JdbcConnectorOptions.PASSWORD, memsqlConfig("pass"))
      .option(JdbcConnectorOptions.TABLE_NAME, "asset")
      .schema(Schema.newBuilder()
        .column("owner_id", DataTypes.STRING)
        .column("id", DataTypes.STRING)
        .column("poi_id", DataTypes.STRING)
        .column("gateway_id", DataTypes.STRING)
        .column("internal_status", DataTypes.STRING)
        .build())
      .build()

    val assetTagTableDescriptor = TableDescriptor.forConnector("jdbc")
      .option(JdbcConnectorOptions.URL, s"jdbc:mysql://${memsqlConfig("host")}:${memsqlConfig("port")}/${memsqlConfig("dbname")}")
      .option(JdbcConnectorOptions.USERNAME, memsqlConfig("user"))
      .option(JdbcConnectorOptions.PASSWORD, memsqlConfig("pass"))
      .option(JdbcConnectorOptions.TABLE_NAME, "asset_tag")
      .schema(Schema.newBuilder()
        .column("owner_id", DataTypes.STRING)
        .column("asset_id", DataTypes.STRING)
        .column("tag_id", DataTypes.STRING)
        .column("role", DataTypes.STRING)
        .build())
      .build()

    tableEnv.createTemporaryTable("asset", assetTableDescriptor)
    tableEnv.createTemporaryTable("asset_tag", assetTagTableDescriptor)


    val assetTable: Table = tableEnv.from(assetTableDescriptor)
      .select($"owner_id" as "asset_owner_id", $"id", $"poi_id", $"gateway_id", $"internal_status")

    val assetTagTable: Table = tableEnv.from(assetTagTableDescriptor)
      .select($"owner_id", $"asset_id", $"tag_id", $"role")

    val assetAssociationTable = assetTable
      .leftOuterJoin(assetTagTable, $"id" === $"asset_id" and $"asset_owner_id" === $"owner_id")
      .select($"asset_owner_id", $"id", $"poi_id", $"gateway_id", $"tag_id", $"role")

    val assetTableStream: DataStream[AssetOperationKafkaMsg] = tableEnv
      .toDataStream(assetAssociationTable, classOf[JdbcAssetState])
      .flatMap(new JdbcAssetStateDataMapper)
```

In a BATCH mode, it works good, but I need to join `assetTableStream` with another stream in my app in STREAMING mode

Based what I found in flink docs looks like I need to use `Lookup Join` but cannot figure out how to do that with table API (not SQL).

Having any small example with joining two jdbc tables and converting it into datastream would be fantastic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two hints:

- If you have a dynamic table that is updated, the stream which is created to reflect these updates is *changelog* (not *append-only*). It means that you have to use `toChangelogStream` method (not `toDataStream` as it is in your example)
- Your join is problematic because of the size of the state which is maintained. Consider using interval join (https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/table/tableapi/#interval-join) if it is possible.